Delphi how to Serialize and Deserialize TObject
I've the following code that deals with TStream writing and reading, but my problem (issue) is reading/writing TILObjects using the TListHelper class. Please read the comments inside these methods:
procedure TListHelper<T>.Serialize(const Buffer: IBuffer; const List: IList<T>);
function TListHelper<T>.Deserialize(const Buffer: IBuffer): IList<T>;

type
  IBuffer = interface
    procedure WriteInteger(Value: Integer);
    function ReadInteger:Integer
  end;

  TBuffer = class(TInterfacedObject, IBuffer)
  private
    FStream: TStream;
  public
    constructor Create(AStream: TStream);
    procedure WriteInteger(Value: Integer);
    function ReadInteger: Integer;
  end;
  
  type
  ILObject = interface
    ['{D4E3A925-58F2-4E8C-93E7-B49C1C3B453D}']
    procedure Serialize(Stream: IBuffer);
    function Deserialize(Stream: IBuffer): ILObject;
  end;


  TILObject = class(TInterfacedObject, ILObject)
  public
    procedure Serialize(Stream: IBuffer); virtual; abstract;
    function Deserialize(Stream: IBuffer): ILObject; virtual; abstract;
  end;

type
  IListHelper<T> = interface
    procedure Serialize(const Buffer: IBuffer; const List: IList<T>);
    function Deserialize(const Buffer: IBuffer): IList<T>;
  end;

  TListHelper<T> = class(TInterfacedObject, IListHelper<T>)
  public
    procedure Serialize(const Buffer: IBuffer; const List: IList<T>);
    function Deserialize(const Buffer: IBuffer): IList<T>;
  end;
// test classes
TChild = class(TILObject)
  private
  public
    constructor Create; overload; override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Serialize(Stream: IBuffer); override;
    class function Deserialize(const Stream: IBuffer): TChild; reintroduce; overload;
  end;
  
  TFather = class(TILObject)
  private
    FChildList: IList<TChild>;
   procedure ReadChild(const Stream: IBuffer);
  public
    constructor Create; overload; override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Serialize(Stream: IBuffer); override;
    class function Deserialize(const Stream: IBuffer): ILObject; reintroduce; overload;
    property ChildList: IList<TChild> read FChildList write FChildList;
  end;

// 
implementation

constructor TBuffer.Create(AStream: TStream);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FStream := AStream;
end;

procedure TBuffer.WriteInteger(Value: Integer);
begin
  FStream.WriteBuffer(Value, SizeOf(Value));
end;

function TBuffer.ReadInteger: Integer;
begin
  FStream.ReadBuffer(Result, SizeOf(Result));
end;

procedure TListHelper<T>.Serialize(const Buffer: IBuffer; const List: IList<T>);
var
  Count, i: Integer;
begin
  Count := List.Count;
  Buffer.WriteInteger(Count);

  for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
  begin
    if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(Integer) then
      Buffer.WriteInteger(Integer(TValue.From<T>(List[I]).AsType<Integer>))
// here how deal with the TILObjects.Serialize
// I want to have TILObject.Serialize(Buffer)
  // else if TILObject
    else
      raise Exception.Create('Unsupported type for List serialization');
  end;
end;

function TListHelper<T>.Deserialize(const Buffer: IBuffer): IList<T>;
var
  Count, i: Integer;
  Item: TValue;
  LObject: TILObject;
begin
  Result := TList<T>.Create;
  Count := Buffer.ReadInt32;

  for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
  begin
    if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(Integer) then
      Item := TValue.From<Integer>(Buffer.ReadInteger)
    // here how to deal with TILObject.Deserialize
   // else if  TILObject.Deserialize(Buffer)
    else
      raise Exception.Create('Unsupported type for List deserialization');

    Result.Add(Item.AsType<T>);
  end;
end;

// test classes
constructor TChild.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
end;

destructor TChild.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TChild.Serialize(Stream: IBuffer);
begin
  inherited Serialize(Stream);
end;

constructor TFather.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FChildList := TList<TChild>.Create;
end;

class function TChild.Deserialize(const Stream: IBuffer): ILObject;
begin
  Result := TChild.Create;
end;

How to use TIlObject.Serialize() inside TListHelper<T>.Serialize() and TILObject.Deserialize() inside TListHelper<T>.Deserialize()?

You already know how to create a TValue from a list item. TValue has IsObject, IsInstanceOf, and AsObject methods.  So, you can get access to a list item as an object, cast the object to ILObject/TILObject as needed, and then call its Serialize()/Deserialize() methods.

@RemyLebeau thank you : if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(Integer)  how to use same with ILObject ? Is this correct if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(TILObject) ?

Don't use TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(Integer), use GetTypeKind(T) = tkInteger instead. Then you can check for tkInterface and tkClass types. Second, you can also create the TValue unconditionally and then use its Kind property.

However, you are going to run into trouble with your TListHelper.Deserialize(). You have to create an object instance to call (T)ILObject.Deserialize() on, so you need to know which class type to create. You can't call T.Create since T doesn't have the class constraint. So you will have to write the class name into your Buffer (easy) and then read it back (easy) and then use a separate factory to create and return an ILObject/TILObject instance from the specified class name (much work).

@RemyLebeau so many thanks ; more details ( IF POSSIBLE PLEASE ) on : " o you will have to write the class name into your Buffer (easy) and then read it back (easy) and then use a separate factory to create and return an ILObject/TILObject instance from the specified class name (much work) "

I posted an answer.

Testing the return value of TypeInfo(T) alone won't help you in this situation, as you would have to test for specific types. Instead, you can use GetTypeKind(T) (XE7+), checking for tkInteger, tkInterface, and tkClass types, and handle their data accordingly.
For example:
procedure TListHelper<T>.Serialize(const Buffer: IBuffer; const List: IList<T>);
var
  Count, i: Integer;
  LIntf: ILObject;
  LObject: TObject;
begin
  Count := List.Count;
  Buffer.WriteInteger(Count);

  for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
  begin
    case GetTypeKind(T) of 
      tkInteger: begin
        Buffer.WriteInteger(TValue.From<T>(List[I]).AsType<Integer>);
      end;
      tkInterface: begin
        if Supports(TValue.From<T>(List[I]).AsInterface, ILObject, LIntf) then
          LIntf.Serialize(Buffer)
        else
          raise Exception.Create('Unsupported interface type for List serialization');
      end;
      tkClass: begin
        LObject := TValue.From<T>(List[I]).AsObject;
        if LObject.InheritsFrom(TILObject) then
          TILObject(LObject).Serialize(Buffer)
        else
          raise Exception.Create('Unsupported object type for List serialization');
      end;
    else
      raise Exception.Create('Unsupported type for List serialization');
    end;
  end;
end;

function TListHelper<T>.Deserialize(const Buffer: IBuffer): IList<T>;
var
  Count, i: Integer;
  Item: TValue;
  LIntf: ILObjct;
  LObject: TILObject;
begin
  Result := TList<T>.Create;
  Count := Buffer.ReadInt32;

  for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
  begin
    case GetTypeKind(T) of
      tkInteger: begin
        Item := TValue.From<T>(Buffer.ReadInteger);
      end;
      tkInterface: begin
        LIntf := ???.Create as ILObject;
        LIntf.Deserialize(Buffer);
        Item := TValue.From<T>(LIntf);
      end;
      tkClass: begin
        LObject := ???.Create as TILObject;
        LObject.Deserialize(Buffer);
        Item := TValue.From<T>(LObject);
      end;
    else
      raise Exception.Create('Unsupported type for List deserialization');
    end;

    Result.Add(Item.AsType<T>);
  end;
end;

However, as you can see above, there is a problem with TListHelper.Deserialize(). You have to create an object instance first in order to call (T)ILObject.Deserialize() on it, so you need to know which class type to create. But you can't call T.Create since T doesn't have the class constraint. So you will have to write the class name into your Buffer, read it back, and use a separate factory to create and return a new (T)ILObject instance for the specified class name, eg:
procedure TListHelper<T>.Serialize(const Buffer: IBuffer; const List: IList<T>);
var
  Count, i: Integer;
  LIntf: ILObject;
  LObject: TObject;
begin
  Count := List.Count;
  Buffer.WriteInteger(Count);

  for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
  begin
    case GetTypeKind(T) of 
      tkInteger: begin
        Buffer.WriteInteger(TValue.From<T>(List[I]).AsType<Integer>);
      end;
      tkInterface: begin
        if Supports(TValue.From<T>(List[I]).AsInterface, ILObject, LIntf) then
        begin
          Buffer.WriteString((LIntf as TObject).ClassName);
          LIntf.Serialize(Buffer);
        end else
          raise Exception.Create('Unsupported interface type for List serialization');
      end;
      tkClass: begin
        LObject := TValue.From<T>(List[I]).AsObject;
        if LObject.InheritsFrom(TILObject) then
        begin
          Buffer.WriteString(LObject.ClassName);
          TILObject(LObject).Serialize(Buffer)
        end else
          raise Exception.Create('Unsupported object type for List serialization');
      end;
    else
      raise Exception.Create('Unsupported type for List serialization');
    end;
  end;
end;

function TListHelper<T>.Deserialize(const Buffer: IBuffer): IList<T>;
var
  Count, i: Integer;
  Item: TValue;
  LClassName: string;
  LIntf: ILObjct;
  LObject: TILObject;
begin
  Result := TList<T>.Create;
  Count := Buffer.ReadInt32;

  for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
  begin
    case GetTypeKind(T) of
      tkInteger: begin
        Item := TValue.From<T>(Buffer.ReadInteger);
      end;
      tkInterface: begin
        LClassName := Buffer.ReadString;
        LIntf := CreateILObject(LClassName) as ILObject; // <--
        LIntf.Deserialize(Buffer);
        Item := TValue.From<T>(LIntf);
      end;
      tkClass: begin
        LClassName := Buffer.ReadString;
        LObject := CreateILObject(LClassName); // <--
        LObject.Deserialize(Buffer);
        Item := TValue.From<T>(LObject);
      end;
    else
      raise Exception.Create('Unsupported type for List deserialization');
    end;

    Result.Add(Item.AsType<T>);
  end;
end;

You will have to implement CreateILObject() yourself, eg:
function CreateILObject(AClassName: string): TILObject;
begin
  if AClassName = 'TChild' then
    Result := TChild.Create
  ...
  else
    Result := nil; // or raise
end;

There are ways to generalize such a factory, but that is outside the scope of this question.  There are many other questions on StackOverflow (and other forums) related to (de)serializing objects.
